# use laptop monitor connecting to my old desktop(which is without monitor)

Tags: display, monitor

I want to use my laptop monitor to work on my old pc, which has no monitor. I have all devices keyboard, mouse, connected to my old computer cabinate, running ubuntu. I have only VGA & USB support on my old pc.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptop screens (the ones built into the laptop lid) have a proprietary connector to the motherboard and aren't directly compatible with VGA (or even DVI) -- in essence, the electronics that would normally be in the monitor, to translate VGA or DVI input to the actual screen addressing (and brightness/color information) for pixel control are incorporated on the laptop's motherboard, to drive the display panel directly.

In order to use the display with another computer, you'd have to have compatible drive electronics from a monitor and a suitable adapter to connect to the laptop's display panel, and you'd have to partially disassemble the laptop to gain access to the ribbon cable that feeds the screen.  This is far from practical, with used XGA flat panel monitors available on eBay for under $50 shipped.

The closest you can come to what you want, in practice, would be to run a graphics terminal (Citrix or similar) on the laptop and use it to log into the headless desktop machine.

Comment: I am not finding it clear installing Citrix(please give me link what and where to download). Also, I have quick-synergy(installed from ubuntu software center) would it help. @Zeiss ikon

Comment: @user276297 Citrix is a commercial product; you have to buy it, rather than download it and I'm not sure it's available for non-Windows operating systems; hence my "or similar".  I mentioned that by way of saying you could buy a monitor for less than the solutions that let you use your laptop screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you old PC is connected to network, do some form of remote login from your laptop to your other PC machine (ssh -X or vnc, etc). If it is not connected to network, but has network support, cross link the two with an Ethernet cable.